# how to add the slugified field

Tags: django, djangoappengine

while creating a blog i am using the following model class and form .but since i don't want the user to add the url(slugified field) himself  i am stuck how  can i add the slugified  url before saving the model,should it be done in the view if i am correct.
PS: i am using app engine where i heard that the slug fields aren't available.

```
  class Post(db.Model):
          title=db.StringProperty(required=True)
            url=db.StringProperty(required=True)
            content_html=db.TextProperty(required=True)
            dateTime=db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True,required=True)
            tags=db.StringListProperty()


class PostForm(djangoforms.ModelForm): 
 class Meta:
  model=Post
  exclude=['url']
```

Comment: Try http://www.smipple.net/snippet/brettsky/SlugProperty%20for%20App%20Engine%20based%20on%20Django%27s%20SlugField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either do this in your view or override your form's save method. If you do it in your view it will look something like this:

```
#views.py
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

def post_create(request, ...):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            slugified_title = str(slugify(title))
            post.url = [modify the slugified_title however you want...]
            post.save()
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can override your form's save method which would look something like:

```
#forms.py
class PostForm(django.forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Post
        exclude=['url']
    def save(self, commit=True, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        post = super(PostForm, self).save(commit=False)
        slugified_title = str(slugify(post.title))
        post.url = [modify the slugfield_title however you want...]
        post.save()
```