# how to add to a FORM in views with django?

Tags: django, forms, view

I've posted back a form and within my view I'd like to add a a field.

Editing the **slug** field. It is the slug field which I've decided to hide in the form and automatically generate it in the view. How can I append the slug field to the form?

```
if form.is_valid():            
    form.[want_to_add_slug_field_here] = slugify(form.cleaned_data['title'])
    form.save()
```

---

I'm using (this is to hide the fields from the front end users completely as I want to automate these.

```
class LinkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Link
        exclude = ('pub_date', 'slug', 'posted_by',)
```

So these fields are not on my form when it's generating. I'm wanting to add these fields into the FORM before the save. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to deal with that (I assume you use ModelForm):

1. Use form's `clean` method:

   ```
   class MyForm(forms.models.ModelForm):
       """ This is a form for your model. It includes all fields, but you
           won't display the slug field to the user. """

       def clean(self):
           cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
           cleaned_data["slug"] = slugify(form.cleaned_data["title"])
           return cleaned_data
   ```
2. Add the slug to the model before commiting:

   ```
   if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.slug = slugify(form.cleaned_data["title"])
        instance.save()
   ```
3. Override your model's save method:

   ```
   class MyModel(models.Model):

       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
            return super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
   ```
4. Use a 3rd party autoslug field, for example [django-autoslug](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug/)

I personally use the 4th way.

Comment: great response. as you can see it's not only for the slug field. i'd also like to be able to manipulate other fields such as 'posted_by' before the save. i don't want to override the def save as i want the admin forms to still all be default.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for:

Default value when displaying form:

```
form.fields['slug_field'].initial = slugify(form.fields['title'].value)
```

Default value with no input from user, ever:
You need to override the save method on the **model** itself:

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.slug_name = slugify(self.title)
    return super(MyModel,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: this assumes the slug_field is part of the form on request. i'm wanting to add a field to the form object.

Comment: Yep sorry I missed that. @andrey-fedoseev 's answer is definitely what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Override the form's save method as explained here: [how to add the slugified field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238401/how-to-add-the-slugified-field/4239495#4239495)

If you slugify fields on a regular basis and on several models you could also consider writing a wrapper around the slugify-function that you can trigger with a [pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save).

Comment: thanks. i updated my question to show that it's not only the slug field that i'm trying to manipulate.